# Altering find command output before passing to AWS S3

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, git-bash

I have to `gzip` CSS and JS files and upload them to AWS S3 bucket. Problem was when I ran `gzip` and tried uploading them, their initial dir structure wasn't retained. Instead, they all got copied to the root folder of S3 bucket. I realized this was happening because of the way `find` command returns the output.

```
$ find . -type f \( -iname \*.js -o -iname \*.css \) -exec gzip -9 "{}" \; -exec mv "{}.gz" "{}" \; -exec aws s3 cp "{}" s3://somebucket/ --dryrun \;
(dryrun) upload: .\service-worker.js to s3://somebucket/service-worker.js
(dryrun) upload: static\css\main.5b39ffb6.css to s3://somebucket/main.5b39ffb6.css
```

To handle the above, I used `{}` in the destination path as well but now the issue is that the final path has `./` (just after the `s3://somebucket/`) as shown below:

```
$ find . -type f \( -iname \*.js -o -iname \*.css \) -exec gzip -9 "{}" \; -exec mv "{}.gz" "{}" \; -exec aws s3 cp "{}" s3://somebucket/{} --dryrun \;
(dryrun) upload: .\service-worker.js to s3://somebucket/./service-worker.js
(dryrun) upload: static\css\main.5b39ffb6.css to s3://somebucket/./static/css/main.5b39ffb6.css
```

I thought I could strip the `./` part from `{}` using `cut` or `sed` using something like this but when I try checking the output, it *decorates* my whole terminal with unreadable stuff. Seems as if it's not working on the output file name but instead on its content. Not sure what's happening.

```
$ find . -type f \( -iname \*.js -o -iname \*.css \) -exec gzip -9 "{}" \; -exec mv "{}.gz" "{}" \; -exec sed 's#^./##' "{}" \;
```

Any way I can fix this so that S3 can copy the files in their correct dir structure?

Comment: Does your `find` have `-execdir`? If so, you can use that instead of the last `-exec`; it changes into the directory of the file before running the command.

Comment: I am trying now on `git-bash` but actual command will run on Alpine or Ubuntu but anyways, `git-bash` has `-execdir`. I came across this option an hour ago :) however, this isn't working and i thought so. Isn't this simply going to traverse to the source file's folder and with `{}` in the destination, it should simply copy the file to the S3's root again? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a subshell in an `-exec` action and manipulate the filenames in there:

```
find . \
    -type f \
    \( -iname '*.js' -o -iname '*.css' \) \
    -exec bash -c '
        f=${1#./}
        gzip "$f"
        mv "$f".gz "$f"
        aws s3 cp "$f" s3://somebucket/"$f" --dryrun' _ {} \;
```

The `-exec` action runs a command `bash -c '<list>' _ {}`: a list of commands, with a dummy parameter `_` assigned to `$0` and the filename assigned to `$1`.

Because we're using `-exec`, the file paths will look like `./static/css/main.5b39ffb6.css`, i.e., still contain the `./` we want to get rid of.

The command `f=${1#./}` removes `./` from the beginning of the path; from now on, we can just use `$f`.

---

You're right that sed modifies the contents of files if they're given as parameters; to change a string directly, you'd have to pipe to sed, as in

```
sed 's/x/y/' <<< 'A string with x'
```

or

```
echo 'A string with x' | sed 's/x/y'
```

Comment: Although i have quite some parameters in S3 command which i excluded while posting this question, if i try just what you suggested with the correct bucket name and nothing else, i get `Unknown options: --dry-run` message three times on console.

Comment: @Technext Oops, typo, it has to be `--dryrun`, not `--dry-run`, sorry about that!

Comment: Oh...sorry, i also didn't notice :) I tried but it's not retaining the original source path and corresponding destination path. Output: `(dryrun) upload: .\main.5b39ffb6.css to s3://somebucket/main.5b39ffb6.css`. Expected output: `(dryrun) upload: static\css\main.5b39ffb6.css to s3://somebucket/static/css/main.5b39ffb6.css`. Similarly for others.

Comment: @Technext Oh, I see. That's caused by `-execdir`, let me update that.

Comment: Thanks for the really nice explanation for `bash -c` option. I came across it long time ago but was not clear that time. Things are far better now. :) Thank you! Any other resource where i can explore more examples?

Comment: @Technext [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) is pretty good; also, watch out for [this injection pitfall](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#find_._-exec_sh_-c_.27echo_.7B.7D.27_.2BAFw.3B).

Comment: Thanks! That link is nice. As an aside, i just thought of using `+` syntax instead of `;` in the above issue but it only displays the first line as output.

Comment: @Technext If you use `{} +`, you have to handle all parameters within `bash -c`, i.e., do something like `files=("${@#./}")` and then deal with that array instead of `f=${1#./}` - not straightforward.

Comment: If i am running the find cmd inside a script and if i am using variable in place of `s3://somebucket/"$f"` i.e., `$s3_prefix/$bucket_name/"$f"`, it's printing blank. I thought it would inherit from the parent shell. In the script, if i try printing the value of both the variables just before running the `find` cmd, it prints the expected value. I checked online and everywhere it says that variables should get inherited in the sub-shell. I am using single quote only for `bash -c ' '`. Any idea what could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @Technext Because the `bash -c` part within `-exec` is single-quoted, you have to so some contortions to get your variables expanded; something like `aws s3 cp "$f" '"$s3_prefix/$bucket_name"'/"$f"`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Benjamin! That exact syntax worked. :) The last [link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) you gave immediately helped me that day as i ran into a case where i had to embed single quotes in the mini-script. Any similar resource for this? :)

Comment: @Technext Maybe https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes? It has an example of the quotes mixing I used.